# Add custom field in order table after HPOS change

Tags: woocommerce

I am using same URL for long time and change real product inside time to time.
It is because I use composite products and parts are keep changing.
But in future, I might need real ERP Stock code, thus I am adding it to orders as extra info.

It was working like a charm till HPOS change. Now I need to update my snippet and have no idea.

How I should change below code to add this field in new order database table?

```
/**
 * Add current SKU code (ERP Stock code) to orders to skip issues in future
 */
    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_erp_stock_code', 4);
    
    function add_erp_stock_code($order_id)
    {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $product = $order->get_items();
        $sku_list = array();
        global $wpdb;
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            if ($product->is_type('composite')) {
                $sku_list[] = array(
                    "sku" => $product->sku,
                    "product_id" => $product_id,
                );
            }
        }
        if(empty(get_post_meta($order_id, "erp_stock_code", true))){
            update_post_meta($order_id, "erp_stock_code", $sku_list);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to provided code, to update order metadata, when woocommerce High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS) is enabled, the following code should be used.

```
if(empty($order->get_meta("erp_stock_code", true))) {
    $order->update_meta_data("erp_stock_code", $sku_list);
    $order->save();      
}
```

Regarding documentation details of woocommerce High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS), the following link can be checked:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/High-Performance-Order-Storage-Upgrade-Recipe-Book.